# Translation help with song title and artist

Tags: translation

[image]I hope you can help me to find the name of the artist on this old record and the song title.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From right to left

梆子 - wooden clapper (a musical instrument )

[image: 梆子]

廣東省城 - Guangdong provincial capital (where the record was published)

特請第一等真正名角 - Specially invited first-class really famous performer

白蛇滿 - Bai Sheman (the actress' name)

花旦 - Cantonese operate female lead performer

陳[杏元憶釵](https://openmuseum.tw/muse/digi_object/2fbe6f141a2acc65d45a83898868d099) - Chen Xingyuan Remember the Hairpin (the song title)

第三 - the third (meaning unknown)

Note: The 花旦 was 白蛇滿

Comment: Thank you so much,  this helps a lot. Best regards to you.